# Openvpn connection with static ip

Tags: ubuntu, static, ip, openvpn, tunnel

Im a complete noob when it comes to VPN and have not really understod what to change to achive static IP adresses for VPN-Clients.

First of all i used this install script https://www.tecmint.com/install-openvpn-in-ubuntu/

Then im using OpenVPN-Connect software to connect with .ovpn credential files!

This is installed on one Windows 7 machine aswell as my Windows 8 laptop - Connecting thru vpn is fine and all. Just that little problem both My laptop and this Windows 7 box is running over a 4G LTE network so alot of reconnects and IP gets rotated alot. Is there some simple (as the noob i am) way to change VPN-setting so windows 7 box always gets 10.8.0.2?

I dont care so much about what ip i get for my laptop just this windows 7 box that needs a static Client-IP inside VPN

I found this https://kifarunix.com/assign-static-ip-addresses-for-openvpn-clients/ however since i use .ovpn files i dont see any user specific .crt files so im out of ideas dont think its correct way to solve my problem. Also i dont want to screw something up that is "working"!

Can someone point me in the correct direction or if someone knows exactly what i should change? Please let me know im lost!

Comment: Do you want your mobile operator to assign your device to always same IP address? If yes, you need to ask your mobile operator to provide you static IP service? It will ensure that after location updates or signal drop cases you will always get to same IP address.

Comment: No i want my "VPN clients" to have "Static" IP, those adresses that the client gets "inside the tunnel itself" to be "static". What ip i get from ISP isnt my problem, just VPN client "Local - LAN" IPs